# Starting previously running Docker containers with GPU support

Tags: gpu, docker, wsl2, cuda, nvidia

I recently set up WSL2 (Windows 10, 21H2) with CUDA/Docker support to train some neural networks. For this I followed the instructions from this guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html

Once I was done, I ran an image as specified in the document I linked:

```
docker run -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

At this point I am able to launch the browser and work on a Jupyter Notebook with GPU support. I verify this by running:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

The output confirms the GPU is available:
`[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]`.

After I'm done I save my changes and stop CTRL-C out of the container.

Up to this point, everything works as I expect.

To resume work I've been using `docker start -i happy_bose` where `happy_bose` is the name of the container I ran earlier.

However, GPU support is non-existent (the call to `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` returns an empty list).

I was expecting `docker start -i happy_bose` to start the container with GPU support but this is not the case. Is there any way to reuse a container with GPU support or do I need to create it and start it using `docker run` every time?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?  If you are not already running 21H2 you should try upgrading to that version before you do anything.

Comment: I am on 21H2 (updated the question to mention this fact). That being said, the problem is not that it does not work at all but that it does not work when I restart a previous container. Unlike `docker run`, `docker start` does not take a `--gpus all` argument, but I think this should not matter if the container was first run using said flag.